# How to access child model static from parent within Coffeescript inhertiance

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have the following `BaseModel` class

```
namespace 'Models', (exports) ->
  class exports.BaseModel
    toJSON: =>
      if @jsonProperties? then ko.toJSON( @, @jsonProperties() ) else null
```

Then my `Profile` class that inherits the `BaseModel` class

```
namespace 'Models', (exports) ->
  class exports.Profile extends exports.BaseModel
    constructor: ( @options ) ->
      @FirstName = ko.observable( @options.FirstName )
      @LastName = ko.observable( @options.LastName )

  @jsonProperties: -> 
    return [ "FirstName", "LastName" ]
```

This allows me to call something like the following

```
profile = new Models.Profile
  FirstName: 'blah'
  LastName: 'blah'   

profile.toJSON()
```

However within the base model `@jsonProperties` is `undefined` because it's kind of like a static function on the class type.  The reason I want this is so that I can reference it in other classes like so `Models.Profile.jsonProperties()`

Is is possible for me to get access to something like this from within the BaseModel?

---

EDIT: Adding in a placeholder fix until I come up with something better

I've done the following to get it working but I'd rather not have to repeat this line in every Model that I create, it seems like there should be a generic way to do this from the BaseModel.

```
namespace 'Models', (exports) ->
  class exports.Profile extends exports.BaseModel
    constructor: ( @options ) ->
      @jsonProperties = Models.Profile.jsonProperties
```

Comment: I figured out a way but it's a touch dangerous - in the BaseModel have function `@json` return `Models[@.constructor.name].jsonProperties()`which accesses the parent.  However this doesn't work for IE.  It's probably possible to get a workaround though.

Comment: Function.name isn't standart AFAIK

Comment: Yeah :( it sucks there's not something in javascript that lets you do this.  Would be really helpful for meta programming

Comment: rel https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1767

Answer (score 3):

If I understood what you are trying to achieve, you can fix it by defining `jsonProperties` as both a "static" Class method and an instance method. Here is a simplified code (don't have access to the `namespace` util and knockout):

```
class BaseModel
  toJSON: =>
    if @jsonProperties? 
      for value in @jsonProperties()
        @[value]
    else
      null

class Profile extends BaseModel
  constructor: ( @options ) ->
    @FirstName = @options.FirstName
    @LastName = @options.LastName

  @jsonProperties: -> 
    return [ "Class FirstName", "Class LastName" ]

  jsonProperties: -> 
    return [ "FirstName", "LastName" ]

prof = new Profile
  FirstName: 'Leandro'
  LastName: 'Tallmaris'   

alert(prof.toJSON());

alert(Profile.jsonProperties());
```

The first alert should give you `Leandro, Tallmaris`, while the second `Class FirstName, Class SecondName`.